# How do I render the main navigation menu?

Tags: 8, external-scripts

In Drupal 7, we were able to render the main navigation menu onto a page outside the main Drupal folders by including bootstrap.inc and displaying it with this code.

```
 $menuData = menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'));
 print drupal_render($menuData);
```

Can something similar be done in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the render Array :

```
  $menuService = \Drupal::service('menu.link_tree');
  $parameters = $menuService->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters('main');
  $mainMenutree = $menuService->load('main', $parameters);
  $renderArray = $menuService->build($mainMenutree);
```

If needed, here is how to generate the HTML

```
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($renderArray);
```

Note : replace 'main' by menu name for another one.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: ! Alas, I can't seem to get it to work though. I'm calling bootstrap.inc like this:

`use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Drupal\Core\Form\EnforcedResponseException;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;

// Change the directory to the Drupal root.
chdir('..');
$autoloader = (require_once './core/includes/bootstrap.inc');`

Is there something else needed? JE

Comment: None of this is needed, the piece of code i gave you is enough, where are you doing this ?

Comment: Hello. In a directory outside of the main Drupal 8 folder structure. Thank you! @Oulalahakabu